# Deploy a Clojure console program in a browser using clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, console, clojurescript

We've been using Clojure for years for scientific computing tasks -- and love it.

Now we're interested in deploying a console-based program online: the UI would just be an interactive console.  Presumably this would require some browser UI element that mimics a terminal, such that ClojureScript could talk to as if it were terminal.

Has anyone attempted this before?

Comment: I haven't done this myself but here are a few resources to review: https://xtermjs.org/ ("Build terminals in the browser"), https://github.com/viebel/klipse ("a JS plugin for embedding interactive code snippets"). Something similar still exists at http://clojurescript.net/

Comment: This is unfortunately off-topic for stack overflow, I'd try [Clojurians slack](https://clojurians.slack.com/messages). "[R]equire some browser UI element" is running in a browser a hard requirement? You may have an easier time with electron.

Comment: @JaredSmith Help us out here -- why is this off-topic for SO?  I'm sure you're right, but don't get it.

Comment: @JohnStewart this site tries really hard to maintain a laser-like focus on being a reference resource for objectively correct answers to specific programming questions about actual code. Questions like yours may be interesting and useful but they tend to be more of a discussion starter (read: opinions,  tangents, and links to offsite resources) than the "Q: How do I do X with Y? A: use Z" format we aim for. Even if that's not what you intended or you don't think it will go in that direction, long experience on the site has taught us that it usually plays out that way in practice.

Comment: So here's your litmus test: could someone answer this, in code, in an answer of *reasonable* length, without using links to off-site resources except as a reference for material contained in the body of the answer itself?

Comment: I've been using SO for at least a decade, almost every day.  I've read thousands of posts.  I don't think this one here is some sort of outlier, since someone could say: sure, use library X.

Comment: @JohnStewart from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." As I said earlier, I think your question is valid and useful, I just think it's off-topic *here*, and I gave you a pretty solid tip on where to get what you need. I'm not trying to be an impediment here.